# Button border transparency on image

Tags: html, css, button

How to make border of the button semi-transparent when positioning it on top of the image like so?

[image]

Comment: Using rgba color model is working just fine, but is there any way to make border transparent when it is only over image. Here is my code i made: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNYVyO

Answer (score 0):

**In CSS**
.button { border: 5px solid rgba(2,4,233, 0.1); }

rgba() <- put your color, the last parameter is the opacity

Answer (score 0):

Please update code **[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPLYza)**

```css
.button {
  width: 218px;
  height: 57px;
  background: #1abc9c;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -28px -109px;
  line-height: 57px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-size: 23px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 7px solid rgba(120,216,197,.5);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  display: none;
}
.image-holder{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}
.image-holder img{
  vertical-align: top;
}
.image-holder:hover .button{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-holder">
  <a href="#" class="button">Go Ahead</a>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: yeah i made it using rgba, but i want it only transparent, when it is over the image like in the link in my question